# How can I display a launch/splash screen in a react-native app without using a package? (iOS specifcally)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I am currently in the process of meeting Apple's updated developer guidelines for a React Native mobile app. The hangup for me has been with using a storyboard for the launch screen.

Overview

The production version of the app is using react-native-splash-screen to handle the splash screen, which is just the company logo. I noticed that the package last had an update published a year ago, so I would like to get away from it and handle the splash screen natively.

Current State

I created a storyboard with Xcode and dropped the package from the repo. I made a few changes to AppDelegate.m, and I was able to display the splash screen for a set period of time. I ultimately don't want to use a timer, I want to hide the splash screen once all of the launch time network calls are finished.

Solution (?)

After combing through articles and posts, I came across what I think is the solution. It was a post on r/reactnative from a couple of years back: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/754y5g/app_flashing_white_after_launch_screen_on_ios_11/

The OP had found a solution and added it in a [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/754y5g/app_flashing_white_after_launch_screen_on_ios_11/do44b6f?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x). The idea is to edit the AppDelegate.m provided by RN to replace the white screen with the same .xib as the launch screen.

- I have a .storyboard and not a .xib
- Their example has a slightly different AppDelegate.m than the app's.
- I don't know a lick of Objective-C

So, my search continued and I found the following post from StackOverflow: [React-Native iOS - How to show a view controller after Launch screen, before initialising react native bridge (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296229/react-native-ios-how-to-show-a-view-controller-after-launch-screen-before-iniCode)

I refactored based on this post and was able to get to my current state.

Code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LaunchScreen" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  UIViewController *backgroundView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LaunchViewController"];
  
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                               moduleName:@"fakeAppName"
                                               initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];// changed color to clearColor

  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  self.window.rootViewController = backgroundView;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  });
  return YES;
}
```

Question

How can I display a splash screen after the launch screen storyboard to cover the time between tapping the app icon and the completion of the loading of the app?

Additionally, I want the splash screen and launch screen to be the same storyboard so that it is a seamless transition from loading to the home screen.

As I said, I don't know Objective-C and have been at a bit of a loss with debugging this. Can anyone offer suggestions or point me to resources that could help me out here?

Self Defense

I used alternating terminology of splash screen and launch screen because Apple identifies them as 2 different things. As I understand it, the launch screen is for OS loading of the app, and the splash screen is for initial in-app loading.

I have also seen quite a few strong opinions on splash screens. The app has initial network calls that require a short loading period, thus I use a splash screen to cover that loading. I am not using it just for the sake of having the logo on your face for longer.

I am familiar with another RN package called react-native-bootsplash.  I am trying to avoid using a package altogether, which is why I am pursuing this solution in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing what you are seeing is related to the white screen that many posts have mentioned.  This is because the JavaScript bundle is still loading, not because you have API calls (assuming they are in `ComponentDidMount`, which is called after `render`.

Although the terminology is often interchanged, I would suggest focusing on `Launch Screen` as this is what Apple uses, and their guidelines specifically suggest not making it feel like a Splash screen.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/launch-screen/

I'd like to rephrase the question for future viewers

"How can I persist my Launch Screen while the JS bundle loads?"

Fortunately, Reacts `RCTRootView` has a property for this, `loadingView`.

Give this a shot,

```
  ...
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LaunchScreen" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  UIViewController *launchScrenViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LaunchViewController"];

  launchScrenViewController.view.frame = self.window.bounds;
  rootView.loadingView = launchScrenViewController.view;

  return YES;
```

Comment: Had to use `UIViewController *launchScrenViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];` instead to get it working. Otherwise, pretty neat!

Answer (score 0):

For React Native use [react-native-bootsplash](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash)

and call `hide()` when ever you'r ready.

see example from above package:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import RNBootSplash from "react-native-bootsplash";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      // …do multiple sync or async tasks
    };

    init().finally(async () => {
      await RNBootSplash.hide({ fade: true });
      console.log("Bootsplash has been hidden successfully");
    });
  }, []);

  return <Text>My awesome app</Text>;
}
```